# Burninate request - countries - city

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I happened upon [this lovely little question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170249/battles-ships-sql-query) that contains the [countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/countries), so I decided to peruse the questions to figure out why we would have this tag and low and behold I fell down the rabbit hole filled with a plethora of tags that are very puzzling:

[countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/countries) and it's closely related friend [country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/country)

If country is too big for you we have [regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regions), [region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/region) and [regioninfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regioninfo). But wait region isn't what you want, we also have [states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/states)(this one might be ok if dealing with application states).

Finally, we also have [city](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/city)!!

None of these have a tag wiki so my question is are these valid tags or should they be burninated?

Comment: [location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/location) might be a good home for many of these questions.

Answer (score 6):

None of the linked tags have wiki tag summary, which makes them very ambigous. On Travel.SE they would be probably correctly understood, but here some of them are used for questions about localization/internationalization issues, some about classes with that names in some API or about generic concept (Region in graphics). Some are just randomly used, because someone has field with such name/concept.

This chaos makes it a hard work to reorganize them.

In my opinion, if no one cared about creating wiki tag, they are for nobody so important, and for the sake of fighting chaos, they should be burnt alive.

Answer (score 3):

These are valid tags, but should be cleaned up and reorganized. Some questions - e.g. those concerning online locations - should be tagged as such.

However, ambiguous tags like [states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/states) should be avoided. I'm not sure what the best way to clean these up is. The first thing that comes to mind is to synonymize all region-based tags into one group, though that has problems with specificity.

It is also possible that we should just leave these as-is, but clean up the *individual* pairings, such as [country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/country) and [countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/countries).

Comment: Maybe we could have country/countries be made synonyms of each other.

Comment: I agree with that, as well as for [tag:regions] and [tag:region]. Not sure if [tag:regioninfo] should be thrown in there, but my guess is yes.

Comment: Don't forget the `#region` code marker in Visual Studio. Some of [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/region+c%23) are about that.

Comment: @madth3 Maybe we could create a [ide-region] tag for that use?  IF enough questions exist to warrant it.